# Split a even-numbered string in c++

Tags: c++, string, split

I am very new to c++. I am trying to split a string that contains even numbered sub strings till there is no even numbered sub string left. For example, if I input AB ABCD ABC, the output should be A B A B C D ABC. I am trying to do it without tokens, because I don't know how to..
What I have so far only split the first even sub string and it doesn't work if I only have 1 sub string. Can someone please help me out? 
Any advise will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
string temp = "";    
void check(string &str, int &i, int &flag)
{
    int count = 0;
    int reminder;
    do
        {
            count++;
            temp += str[i];
            i++;        
        } while (str[i] != ' ');

    i = i - temp.size();

    reminder = count % 2;
    if (reminder == 0)
        flag = 1;
    else
        flag = 0;
}

void SplitEvenWord(string &str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        check(str, i, flag);
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            temp.insert(temp.size() / 2, " ");
            str.replace(i, temp.size() - 1, temp);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have two functions here. Which have you tested? What should the input and output be for each, and what input causes them to malfunction?

Comment: @Beta, it's going to run in a GUI environment and get input from text boxes. I tested both of them together since the 2nd one only runs when the 1st one is true. So in the text box I would input a random string like ABC ABCD and expect an output of ABC A B C D

Answer (score 2):

There are two skills that are absolutely vital in software engineering (Well, more than two, but two for now): **developing new functions in isolation, and testing things in the simplest possible way.**

You say that the code fails if there is only one substring. You don't say *how* it fails (I should have mentioned clear error reports in the list) so I don't know whether to test your code with an even-length string which it ought to split ("ABCD" => "A B C D") or an odd-length string which it ought to leave alone ("ABC" => "ABC"). Before I try to code these up, I look at your first function:

```
void check(string &str, int &i, int &flag)
{
  ...
  do
    {
        count++;
        temp += str[i];
        i++;
    } while (str[i] != ' ');
  ...
}
```

Trouble already. The strings I have in mind do not contain any spaces, so the loop cannot terminate. This code will run past the end of the string into whatever happens to be in that memory space, which will cause **undefined behavior.** (If you don't know that term, it means that there's no telling what will happen, but if you're lucky the program will just crash.)

Fix that, try running that code on "ABC" and "ABCD" and "A" and "" and "ABC DEF", and get it working perfectly. Once it does, take a look at your other function. Don't test it with random typing, test it with *short, clearly defined strings.* Once it works perfectly, try longer, more complicated ones. If you find a string which causes it to fail, hold onto it! That string will lead you to a bug.

That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer because it was too long to fit as a comment.

I have a couple of suggestions that may help you to figure out what the problem is.

1. Separate "check" into at least two functions, one to split the string into individual words and check them and one to check the length of the string.
2. Test the "check" and "tokenize" functions by separately and see if they give you the expected answers. Work on them individually until they are correct.
3. Separate the formatting of the answers out of "SplitEvenWord" into a separate function.
4. "SplitEvenWord" should then be nothing more than calling the functions you created as a result of the steps above.

When I'm stuck, I always try to break the problem down into small bite sized pieces that I know I can get working. Eventually, the problem becomes assembling the already working pieces of the solution into a larger function that solves the original problem.